# Pandas subtract rows where col a equals x from rows where col a equals y

Tags: python, pandas

My dataframe looks like...

Columns : source, dest, buyOrSell, qty

What I would like is to treat source and dest like a composite key. So, I think I would group by source and dest, and for all rows where buyOrSell == 'buy', get a total sum of qty. For all rows where buyOrSell == 'sell', subtract that qty.

I can first aggregate some duplication by summing where the first three fields are the same:

```
df = df.groupby(['source','dest','buyOrSell']).sum()
```

but have no idea how to get the difference of buys - sells without taking the data out of Pandas

if data is:

```
    source  | dest  | buyOrSell | qty
    A         B       buy         3
    A         C       buy         1
    A         B       sell        1
```

I would like results of:

```
    source  | dest  | buyOrSell | qty
    A         B       buy         2
    A         C       buy         1
```

Comment: df.loc[df['buyOrSell ']=='sell','qty']=-df['qty'], then do your groupby

Comment: @Wen-Ben, that's brilliant. You should post it

Comment: @Vaishali hah no worry

Comment: @Wen-Ben, Yep I was able to get what I wanted based on your help. Thank you so much!